# How do I display a block on a page

Tags: blocks

I simply want to display a table generated from an external database on a page.  In researching this I found it would be easiest to do it by writing a module.  Using a tutorial I created a block module that does what I want, but I can't figure out how to make a block module appear on a normal page. This must be something people do on a regular basis.  This is version 7.

Is there such a thing as a page module rather than a block module?

Thanks,
Jim

Just to extend this a bit, eventually I want to be able to add a select form element and perhaps write a bit of javascript (jQuery calls) to change the query that generates the table, etc.  But for now just to be able to display the table on a node/page would be fine.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly...you can manage your blocks, including what pages they appear on, at http://mysite.com/admin/structure/block

Comment: That's my point, I don't want to put data in a region I want it on the page, node 13 for instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to tackle this...

1. If you're coding the node content yourself you can use the following snippet to get the output of a particular block into a string:

   ```
   $block = block_load($module, $delta);
   $render_array = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
   $output = render($render_array);
   ```
2. There's the [Block Reference](http://drupal.org/project/blockreference) module

   > Defines a field type Block reference which creates a relationship to a block and allows the block to be displayed as the content of the field. It saves this relationship using the block's bid, not its delta + module.

Comment: @user1424074, it is same as my first option :)

Answer (score 0):

You can render a block using the following code snippet in your template file.

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
print render($block['content']);
?>
```

The template file would be **page.tpl.php** for every page, but for a specific page, let's say your have a page **node/13**, you may have a custom page template **page--node--13.tpl.php** for that page.

But I think the good practice is to create a variable in `hook_preprocess_page()` and make it avaibable to the template. Then print it in **page.tpl.php**.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if(isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->nid == 13){
        $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
        $variables['myblock'] = render($block['content']);  
    }
}
```

OR, another way is to use the [Panel](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module to create a custom page in which you can create layouts and place any content such as blocks, nodes, views, forms, etc.

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized
>   layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content
>   manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content
>   within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to
>   create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even
>   override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you
>   can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained
>   permissions.

Comment: For the future, the Panels module looks like it will be useful. Thanks

Comment: @user1424074, Not now? :)

Comment: I don't currently have the time to implement it.  Since the simple solution solved my current need, when I need the more complex solution, I'll investigate it more thoroughly. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the block directly in your body, using [Insert Block](http://drupal.org/project/insert_block) module :

> [block:name of module=delta of block]
>
> ...will insert the contents of a rendered sidebar block into the body
>   of your node. If no delta is specified, the default block for that
>   module will be displayed.

Comment: By 'rendered sidebar block' does that mean it has to appear in a region somewhere for it to be visible on my page?

Comment: @user1424074, it says in the body of your node.